# ArrayAdapter draw view for some row(not for all row) in arraylist

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my application I am populating ListView from ArrayList by using customize ArrayAdapter.
In every row of ArrayList(In the object) one Flag(boolean) is there. If flag it true then populate this row other wise do nothing.

Suppose:-  (one class which contain one String and one boolean, say classA)

```
ArrayList<classA> listA
```

now want to populate ListView only for those row of ArrayList(here listA) whose boolean type is true in the object(here classA boolean)

I try this:-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (listA.get(position).isFlagChanged()) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
        TextView tViewProNameFrmLstViewBasket = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tView);

        return rowView;
    }
    return null;
}
```

in this case it throwing nullPointerException.

I try this also:-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

    if (listA.get(position).isFlagChanged()) {

        TextView tViewProNameFrmLstViewBasket = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tView);

        return rowView;
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

but it also it draw view for false Flag but content is empty.

Comment: Remove all the Objects from the ArrayList whose flag is set to `false`...

Comment: you can populate array list only your required data . if any changes in data you can notifiydatasetchanged method.

Comment: Where you set your arraylist data in textview?

Comment: @GopalRao ... further I need to do some other task also therefore I am not able to remove those object whose Flag is false or I not create other arraylist which contain only true flag object

Comment: @VinitVikash hmmm... I didn't get u what u are saying. You can create a new ArrayList and add all objects to this list whose flag is set `true` and use this list as dataset for your `ListView`...

Answer (score 0):

Returning `null` in `getView` method will crash your `ListView` every time. I would suggest you do the following:

first, filter the `ArrayList`, e.g.:

```
final List<Something> filteredList = new ArrayList<Something>(unfilteredList.size());
for (Something item : unfilteredList) {
  if (item.isFlagChanged()) { filteredList.add(item); }
}
```

secondly, use the `filteredList` to populate your adapter.

Comment: In my ListView there is an option to remove row when user Long press on that row. If I do as u mention above than it remove row in new created Arraylist not in the original arraylist. That's why I am not able to do what u mention above.

Comment: @VinitVikash So when user long presses, remove the corresponding object from both original arraylist and newly created arraylist

Comment: @Gopal Rao for this I need to add some parameter like Id in classA and need to match the id (using for loop) then need to delete that row from original Arraylist. Lot of extra code I need to write to achive this task. I will do this if there is no other option.